# Building a custom UI component library on top of material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am looking to create an angular app. I want the final product to look a very specific way, far from what material looks like right now. However, I want to move fast to iterate on my product. I don't want to spend a ton of time reimplementing logic that is already available in angular/material.

I am thinking about wrapping every material component I want to use in a custom component. For example, I'd create a `ui-tooltip` component that wraps the material tooltip. Then, in `ui-tooltip.style` I'd force my own styles using the `!important` tag.

Is this how I should go about doing this? Is it possible to radically change the design of material while keeping the functionality? Are there projects you can point me to who've done this before?

Comment: Yes it is possible !!! About other project didn't see one if u make one it will be first one i think ;]

Comment: I'm not sure how much you want to change the styles, but you can update the angular material styles easily in your styles.scss, For example, the tooltip, you can update the styles by using .mat-tooltip class

Answer (score 2):

If you think that Material, with just some tweaks will do what you want, that's great.  If you want functionality changes, then extending components is a great way to do that.  For example, I was on one team that created our own Toast-style component that could be positioned anywhere we wanted, not just at the edge of the screen.  I was also on a team that combined the [multi-select component](https://stackblitz.com/angular/rdrllxodmkv?file=app%2Fselect-reset-example.ts) with a [chip list](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview)

However, if you want to use primarily the same functionality while only changing the look and feel I recommend creating a [custom material theme](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming). The docs focus mainly on colors, however using mixins will let you drill down into an Angular Material component to change things like sizing, padding, and margins.

Comment: Thanks! Do you see me running into issues with dependencies or anything if I choose to wrap all my usage of material in my own ui lib? I'd do so just in case I want to change the functionality of a component I had (like `ui-toast`) by removing the material dependency within it and then changing it. Mainly - are mat's components pretty self contained so I can eventually (if needed) rip all imports of them out later down the road?

Comment: I, personally, do not understand the purpose of wrapping a component if you do not plan to make changes to it.  You're creating yourself a lot of busy work to expose inner component properties or methods to your component.  I haven't drilled down deep into the code behind mat components, but I believe there are a lot of internal dependencies among them.